# Как запретить пользователю вводить что-то иное, кроме цифр с пробелами?

Tags: python, input

Есть необходимость получения от пользователя строки, включающей в себя только цифры через пробел (от одной цифры до нескольких, разделенных между собой пробелами).
Нужно реализовать проверку ввода.
Я попытался занести данные от пользователя в список и уже в списке проверять на валидность.
Вот код:

```
inp = input("Введите через пробел цифры: >> ")
inp_list = inp.split()
intgr = []
for x in inp_list:
    try:
        x = int(x)
        intgr.append(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Но это что-то громоздкое. Да и итоговый список не доступен извне этого фрагмента кода, а делать его глобальной переменной не хорошо.
Есть ли более изящные варианты? А на стадии ещё инпута нет возможности отсечь некорретные данные?
Спасибо.

Comment: Переменную списка можно передавать в качестве параметра. В этом случае это работает как передача по ссылке.

Comment: `if all(substr.isdigit() for substr in inp.split()): ...` - проверит, что строка состоит из чисел, разделенных пробелом.

Comment: А вообще, постановка задачи в заголовке и то, что Вы попытались сделать - это разные вещи. Что, всё-таки, Вы хотите сделать? Наложить ограничения на ввод или проверять ввод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете попробовать регулярные выражения. Тоже не коротко, но действенно.

```
import re
x = input("Введите через пробел цифры: >> ")
r = re.search(r'^[0-9 ]+$', x) #проверяет, состоит ли строка только из чисел и пробелов
answer = x if r else False #записывает в переменную строку из input, если она прошла проверку, иначе False
print(answer)

#Можно оформить функцией, чтобы её результат передавать глобально в другие функции
inp = input("Введите через пробел цифры: >> ")

def validator(x):
    r = re.search(r'^[0-9 ]+$', x)
    answer = x if r else False
    return answer

print(validator(inp))
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Чтоб не отображался ввод:

```
curses.noecho()
```

потом пишешь свою функцию `input` на основе `stdscr.getch()`

Так не хотелось писать код, но не удержался:

```
import curses
import sys

def intinput():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    res = []
    tmp = ''
    curses.flushinp()
    print(res, end='← ')
    while True:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        c = stdscr.get_wch()
        if c.isdigit():
            tmp += c
            print(c, end='')
        elif c in [' ', '\n']:
            if tmp:
                res.append(int(tmp))
            tmp = ''
            print('\r', end='')
            print(res, end='← ')
        if c == '\n':
            print('\n')
            break
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    return res

intinput()
```